# Не принимать SIGINT в child процессах multiprocessing (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

```
for r in range(0,REPEATS):
    p=subprocess.Popen(["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-autoexit", FILENAME])
    print "start audio"
    p.communicate()
```

Когда запущен ffplay он принимает сигналы, закрывается и программа идет дальше по  циклу.

Так же происходит, когда я закрываю консольное окно в собранной программе.
Хотя тут странность, если я указал файл wav, то программа закроется, а если Mp3 то продолжит цикл.

Как сделать, чтобы `child` процессы игнорили сигналы?

Comment: communicate возвращает кортеж (stdout, stderr). Если проверить stderr, то может получиться, что ffplay вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: да нет там никакой ошибки, он просто принимает ^c и закрывается.в  итоге освобождается очередь и запускается второй

Answer (score 1):

### Unix

На Unix можно передать функцию, которая включает игнорирование желаемых сигналов, через `Popen(preexec_fn)` параметр, например:

```
preexec_fn=lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

Если дочерний процесс устанавливает свой обработчик, то этот вызов не будет иметь эффект (обработчик всё равно позже будет переписан).

В этом случае вместо игнорирования сигнала, можно сделать так, чтобы по Ctrl-C сам сигнал просто не посылался процессу. Для этого его можно в другую группу процессов отправить (Ctrl-C только текущей активной группе посылается) задав `start_new_session=True` (или снова через `preexec_fn=os.setsid` (новая сессия), `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` (только новая группа как правило):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('ping 127.0.0.1', shell=True, start_new_session=True)
```

#### Windows

На Винде `preexec_fn` не работает, а `start_new_session=True` по-прежнему передаёт Control-C.

`signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)` работает внутри самого Питон процесса и на Windows (`KeyboardInterrupt` не выбрасывается по Ctrl-C в этом процессе), но дочерний процесс, например, созданный с помощью `multiprocessing.Process` должен сам снова `signal()` вызывать (согласно результатам экспериментов на моей машине с Windows 7 и CPython 3.5.1).

Чтобы дочерний процесс не умирал по Ctrl-C, можно также новую группу создать (но со специфичным для Windows API):

```
subprocess.check_call('ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10',
                      creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

Подробнее о [перехвате сигналов в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573288/23044) вообще и о [Control-C в Питоне](https://vorpus.org/blog/control-c-handling-in-python-and-trio/#the-precedent-control-c-in-regular-python) в частности.

Comment: это только  для Unix. в винде не будет работать

Comment: @JohnDoe: вы пробовали?

Comment: да, давно......

Comment: @JohnDoe: [*"On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, `SIGINT`, SIGSEGV, or SIGTERM"*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

Comment: ну вот, SIG_IGN то нету. нечем Игнорить SIGINT

Comment: @JohnDoe SIG_IGN однозначно есть. Обновите вопрос и покажите полный traceback. Укажите точные версии Питона, Windows.

Comment: да где же он есть то https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx

Comment: и была бы ошибка хоть. просто ничего не делает и все

Comment: @JohnDoe 1- вы понимаете что Питон может эмулировать функциональность отсутствующую на системе? 2- если нет ошибки, то что означает ваша фраза *"SIG_IGN то нету"* (например, в качестве доказательства вы могли бы `AttributeError` показать при попытке использования `signal.SIG_IGN`).

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-autoexit", '3.mp3'],stderr=sys.stdout,preexec_fn=init_worker)

Comment: ValueError: preexec_fn is not supported on Windows platforms

Comment: окей?...........

Comment: @JohnDoe с этого и надо было начинать. (один шаг сделали). Шаг номер два: что происходит, если `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` без `preexec_fn` в родителе вызвать?

Comment: он с ним и запускается, чтоб срабатывал except KeyboardInterrupt:

Comment: @JohnDoe что эта ваша фраза означает: у вас в коде присутствует вызов signal, но вы попрежнему получаете KeyboardInterrupt при нажатии Ctrl+C?

Comment: нет не получаю, как только закончатся ffplay программу можно нормально закрыть

Comment: @JohnDoe: я добрался до машины c Windows: `signal(SIGINT,  SIG_IGN)` работает и на Windows, но если хочется Ctrl+C остановить, то можно `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` использовать. Обновил ответ.