# Перехват сигналов в Python

Tags: c++, python, процесс, обработка-сигналов, python-internals

Есть две программы, общающиеся между собой по именованным каналам. Одна на C++, вторая на Python. Причём первая запускает вторую (стандартным способом, через fork + exec).

Участок коммуникации родительской программы (C++):

```
// ...
int pipeDescr;
std::string outputPipeName{"inputPipe"};
std::string inputPipeName{"outputPipe"};
char *message = new char[BUFSIZE];
// ...
while (true)
{
    int bytesNumber = 0;
    // ...
    if ((pipeDescr = open(outputPipeName.c_str(), O_WRONLY)) <= 0)
        break;

    bytesNumber = write(pipeDescr, message, strlen(message));
    if (bytesNumber <= 0)
        break;

    close(pipeDescr);

    message[0] = '\0';
    if ((pipeDescr = open(inputPipeName.c_str(), O_RDONLY)) <= 0)
        break;

    bytesNumber = read(pipeDescr, message, BUFSIZE);
    if (bytesNumber <= 0)
        break;

    close(pipeDescr);
    // ...
}
```

В отдельном потоке работает функция watchDog, которая несёт ответственность за работу дочернего приложения на Python.

```
void watchDog(int clientSocket, pid_t pid, bool &stopWatchDog)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Дочерняя программа завершилась с ошибкой
        if (waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG) != 0)
        {
            // ...
        }

        // Родительская программа закрывается
        mutexClosing.lock();
        if (closing)
        {
            mutexClosing.unlock();
            if (waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG) == 0)
            {
                kill(pid, SIGTERM);
                waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
            }
            break;
        }
        mutexClosing.unlock();

        // Программное отключение WatchDog-а
        mutexWatchDog.lock();
        if (stopWatchDog)
        {
            if (waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG) == 0)
            {
                kill(pid, SIGTERM);
                waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
            }
            mutexWatchDog.unlock();
            break;
        }
        mutexWatchDog.unlock();
    }
}
```

При этом есть три исхода:

- падение дочерней программы
- завершение родительской программы
- завершение дочерней программы без завершения родительской

В последних двух вариантах необходимо плавно завершить дочернюю программу, поэтому, я отправляю ей сигнал SIGTERM и ожидаю завершения.

Участок коммуникации дочерней программы (Python):

```
def sigterm_handler(signal, frame):
    print('\nGot sigterm!\n')
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    input_pipe_name = "inputPipe"
    output_pipe_name = "outputPipe"
    # ...
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
    # ...
    while True:
        pipe_descr = os.open(input_pipe_name, os.O_RDONLY)
        request = os.read(pipe_descr, 10000)
        os.close(pipe_descr)

        reply = work_func(request)

        pipe_descr = os.open(output_pipe_name, os.O_WRONLY)
        os.write(pipe_descr, bytes(reply, 'UTF-8'))
        os.close(pipe_descr)
```

В код я добавил обработку сигнала SIGTERM. Однако, при передаче этого сигнала, функция sigterm_handler не вызывается.

Но! Если написать что-то типа этого:

```
def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

    while True:
        print('waiting...')
        time.sleep(2)
```

То функция вызовется.

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему!

Comment: после `while True:` добавьте `time.sleep(1)`, и проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator добавил - заработало. В чём загвоздка?

Comment: просто не сможет поймать без ожидания. нужно немного ждать, чтобы выдать сигнал для процесса.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator понял. Но в таком случае, если программа встанет на ожидании данных при чтении из трубы, сигнал обработать не получится?

Comment: в питоне не должна встать, насколько знаю.  но можно попробовать в С++ вставить ожидалку и посмотреть результат: если заработает, то уже там обработать на исключение.

Comment: Проверил. Если дать сигнал, когда скрипт встал на чтение из трубы, но с другого конца данные ещё не пришли - сигнал не отрабатывает. Однако, можно удалить файл трубы в приложении-родителе и функция чтения кинет исключение, в котором можно обработать всё необходимое. Или можно сделать два потока. В одном, главном, "ловец" сигналов, в другом всё остальное. Как лучше?

Comment: предлагаю пойти легким путем: добавить слип и не плодить лишний код. помни, что каждая строка кода потенциально может содержать баги.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator говорю же, сигнал не обработается, если скрипт встанет на чтении (точнее на os.open). Но да ладно, вопрос я считаю решённым. Спасибо!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46250/discussion-between-senior-automator-and-accumplus).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Signal handling in multi-threaded Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25676835/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При получении сигнала, обработчик в Си выставляет флаг и сразу же завершается (здесь и далее я описываю СPython реализацию). Обработчик, написанный на Питоне, выполняется только когда контроль возвращается к главному потоку интерпретатора, что происходит позже (например, на следующем [байткоде](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytecode)) или никогда. [Цитата из официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers):

> A Python signal handler does not get executed inside the low-level (C)
>   signal handler. Instead, the low-level signal handler sets a flag
>   which tells the virtual machine to execute the corresponding Python
>   signal handler at a later point(for example at the next bytecode
>   instruction)

Когда контроль возвращается зависит от того, где выполнение происходит в данный момент (разное поведение возможно для разных функций на разных версиях Питона на разных платформах). Например, [`os.open()` на POSIX системе на Python 3.5, сводится к](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b4c2c7f72d000612511f333eeb56793865ddf63/Modules/posixmodule.c#L7469-#L7537):

```c
do {
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    fd = open(path->narrow, flags, mode);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
} while (fd < 0 && errno == EINTR && !(async_err = PyErr_CheckSignals()));
```

`Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` макрос отпускает GIL, что позволяет другим потокам выполнять Питон-код, пока текущий поток блокирован на [`open(2)` системном вызове](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).

При установлении своего обработчика [`signal.signal()` вызов сбрасывает `SA_RESTART` флаг](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.siginterrupt) поэтому системные вызовы такие как `open(2)` прерываются сигналом и возвращают `EINTR`, что в данном случае вызывает [`PyErr_CheckSignals()` функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_CheckSignals), которая ничего не делает, если вызов не из главного потока в программе. В главном потоке `PyErr_CheckSignals()` проверяет был ли сигнал (по флагу, установленному Си обработчиком) и вызывает обработчик, написанный на Питоне. Если обработчик выбросит исключение, то `PyErr_CheckSignals()` возвращает не ноль и цикл прерывается, что ведёт к возникновению исключения на месте вызова `os.open` в Питон коде, когда `os.open` был вызван из главного потока (иначе [`PyErr_CheckSignals()` возвращает `0`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c21f17c6e9d3218812b593f6ec5647e91c16896b/Modules/signalmodule.c#L1495-#L1547)).

В других случаях возможно много вариантов: отпущен/не отпущен GIL (в Си коде), прерывается/автоматически перезапускается ли сам блокирующий вызов (от платформы, Си библиотеки, версии Питона может зависеть), вызывается ли `PyErr_CheckSignals()` в главном потоке, не сбрасывается ли где-то флаг, что сигнал произошёл до вызова обработчика ([`signal(SIGINT, custom_handler)` не работает на Windows на Python 2.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue18040)).

Если вы не можете изменить ваш блокирующий Си код, чтобы он `PyErr_CheckSignals()` вызывал, как это делает `os.open` при получении сигнала, то чтобы обойти это: вызывайте блокирующий код в фоновом потоке, а в главном потоке, спите с небольшим интервалом (это не спасёт, если ваше Си расширение для CPython не отпускает GIL, как это к примеру `re` модуль может делать):

```py
import threading

background_thread = threading.Thread(target=fifo_loop)
background_thread.daemon = True
background_thread.start()
while background_thread.is_alive():
    background_thread.join(1)
    # здесь никакого другого кода, это весь цикл
```

Обратите внимание, что это отличается от предложения добавить `time.sleep(1)` в ваш цикл, который с [FIFO(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) работает. Если сигнал произойдёт вне вызова `time.sleep(1)` в вашем fifo цикле, то проблема так и останется.

Обходное решение работает, потому что цикл с fifo исполняется в фоновом потоке, а главный поток только спит с перерывами. В Питоне 3, можно `background_thread.join()` использовать без `timeout` ([в Питоне 2, этот `.join()` не прерывался сигналами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631441/4279)).

Comment: Выглядит красиво. Буду пробовать, спасибо!

Comment: В целом работает, но есть моменты, когда скрипт "виснет" на sys.exit(0)... Пока что не понял, из-за чего это происходит.

Comment: Нашёл решение. Вместо sys.exit() использую os._exit()

Comment: @AccumPlus sys.exit() работает как raise SystemExit (stdout до конца выводится, `atexit` зарегистрированные обработчики выполняются)—работает только из главного потока (не daemon потоки продолжают жить). `os._exit(0)` тупо убивает весь процесс. Такие вещи лучше ввиде отдельного Stack Overflow вопроса задавать с [*минимальным* примером кода(не нужно тащить весь C++,Python код, если проблему можно продемонстрировать с мéньшим кодом)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ага, я посмотрел, чем они отличаются.

Answer (score 2):

после `while True:` необходимо добавить  `time.sleep(1)`, так как нужно немного ждать, чтобы выдать сигнал для процесса.

p.s. взято из комментариев

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` в лучшем случае может сделать проблему менее вероятной, но он её не устраняет.