# Как прерывать функцию через определенное время при отсутствии голоса или шума?

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Подскажите, есть функция

```
def microphone():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    print("Скажи что - нибудь!")
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        print("Понял, идет распознавание...")
    try:
        statement = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru_RU")
        statement = statement.lower()
        print("Вы сказали: ", statement)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Упс! Кажется, я тебя не поняла, повтори еще раз")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Не могу получить данные от сервиса Google Speech Recognition; {0}".format(e))
```

для распознавания речи, мне нужно чтобы при отсутствии голоса или шума функция работала 20 секунд а после останавливалась. Можно это как-то реализовать ?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Таймер в Python: выйти из программы если пользователь не предоставил ввод за указанное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694130/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Как именно перестать слушать при слишком долгой тишине, зависит от конкретного API которое вы используете (общие методы для async случая, специфичные вызовы для блокирующего кооперативного многопоточного api, вплоть до использования отдельных процессов для некооперативных случаев с Си расширениями). К примеру, используя `sound.Recorder` класс из [Pythonista for iOS](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/index.html), чтобы прервать главный поток (в котором записываем), спустя `delay` секунд тишины, определяемой `silence_level`:

```
import time
from _thread import interrupt_main

def interrupt_on_silence(recorder,
                         delay=10,
                         silence_level=-10,
                         timer=time.monotonic):
    """Interrupt main thread after *delay* seconds of silence if recording."""
    deadline = timer() + delay
    while timer() < deadline:
        if recorder.meters['peak'][0] > silence_level:  # broken silence
            deadline = timer() + delay  # reset deadline
        time.sleep(.1)
    if recorder.recording:
        interrupt_main()
```

код в цикле отодвигает предел времени каждый раз когда нарушена  тишина. По окончанию цикла, основной поток прерывается, если всё ещё запись идёт.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы прервать некооперирующий блокирующий вызов (когда даже [обработка сигналов в Питон коде отложена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573078/23044)), можно его поместить в отдельный процесс и убить его при наступлении желаемого события (псевдо-код):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from time import monotonic as timer

# call the function in a separate process
p = mp.Process(target=uninterruptable_function) 
p.start()

# detect long silence
delay = 20
deadline = timer() + delay
while timer() < deadline and p.is_alive():
    if too_loud():  # broken silence 
        deadline = timer() + delay  # reset deadline
    time.sleep(.1)

# kill the process if necessary
if p.is_alive(): # the call is still active
    p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Если вы просто хотите через 20 секунд прервать вызов:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# call the function in a separate process
p = mp.Process(target=uninterruptable_function) 
p.start()

p.join(20)  # wait until the process is dead, at most 20 seconds

# kill the process if necessary
if p.is_alive(): # the call is still active
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

См. [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/4279).