# Включить консьюмер на несколько секунд

Tags: python, многопоточность, rabbitmq, timeout

Есть 2 потока, взаимодействующих c сервером **RabbiMQ** (библиотека **pika**):

В одном запускается *Producer*, отправляет сообщение и процесс заканчивается.

В другом - *Consumer*. Запускается первым. Ждёт пока Producer не отправит сообщение. Затем *коллбек* консьюмера перехватывает сообщение и обрабатывает его (в коллбеке также закрывается соединение -> поток заканчивает свою работу).

Есть вероятность, что до консьюмера сообщение может и не дойти.

Как задать ему время работы?

Варианта 2:

1. Запустить 3ий поток, который остановит работу консьюмера (=>
   соответсвенно поток консюмера тоже прекратит свою работу) через
   какое-то время.
2. В настройках консьюмера установить какой-то таймаут. Только какой
       параметр за это отвечает(пробовал *heartbeat*,
       *blocked_connection_timeout* и *socket_timeout* - не получается).

Интересует реализация второго варианта.

Comment: если вы параметры уже конкретные обсуждаете, то стоит минимальный полный пример кода привести [mcve]. Вы не пробовали асинхронным интерфейсом воспользоваться без всяких потоков? При использовании потоков и блокирующих функций, для timeout нужна кооперация со стороны этих конкретных блокирующих функций и вообще потоки снаружи нехорошо пытаться убить. В случае асинхронного интерфейса, есть общий для избранной библиотеки способ timeout усилить (к примеру, `gevent.Timeout`, `asyncio.wait_for`, `IOLoop.run_sync`, `trio.move_on_after`, etc).

Comment: Большое спасибо. Пока остановился на том, чтобы вынести работу паблишера и консьюмера в отдельные скрипты. А их уже запускать с помощью suprocess (там и timeout есть)

Comment: да, использование отдельного процесса это тяжёлый, но надёжный способ прервать некооперирующую блокирующую функцию, [пример c multiprocessing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790491/23044). Вы посмотрите ещё предоставляет ли pika api что-то более специфичное, менее тяжеловесное.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае помог метод `add_timeout(deadline, callback_method)`

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

def callback_timeout():
    channel.close()
    connection.close()

deadline = 10 # в секундах

add_timeout(deadline, callback_method)
...
```