# Как ограничить время работы сценария?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x

Как ограничить время работы сценария? Например я поставил чтобы через 5 минут программа закрылась, она работает и как только 5 минут пройдет программа закроется. Как это можно реализовать? В windows.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как прерывать функцию через определенное время при отсутствии голоса или шума?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789906/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код сценария выполняется в функции `run`. Функция `join` ждет указанное количество времени, блокируя дальнейшее выполнение кода в главном потоке. После окончания указанного времени скрипт напечатает в консоль сообщение и закроется.

Параметр `daemon=True` указывает, что поток при завершении главного потока также завершится:

```
import time
import threading


def run():
    i = 1

    # Бесконечный цикл
    while True:
        print i
        i += 1

        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    thread.join(5 * 60)

    print 'Quit!'
```

Comment: для 2-го pythona будет `thread = threading.Thread(target=run)`, а потом только назначить `thread.daemon = True`

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: здесь следует `multiprocessing`, а не `threading`использовать. Последнее не достаточно на CPython, чтобы прервать исполнение вовремя. [Пример кода](https://repl.it/@zed1/threading-fail-to-timeout)

Comment: @jfs, сильная задержка в реализации на CPython? А можно подробнее или ссылку? В соседнем ответе уже есть пример с `multiprocessing`

Comment: ваше решение не работает для функций, которые GIL не отпускают (такие как в моём примере по ссылке)

Comment: @jfs, понял. Спасибо за замечание!

Answer (score 4):

варант 1 простой

```
import time
start_time=time.time()

while (time.time() - start_time) < 300:
  pass # ваши действия
```

вариант 2

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def your_func():
    pass # ваши действия

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=your_func)
    p.start()

    # Ждём 300 секунд (5 минут) 
    p.join(300)

    # Если процесс живой,то убиваем его
    if p.is_alive():
        print "Kill it."

        # Terminate
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: @gil9red да, конечно, спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 2):

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
CLOSE_AFTER = 300 # время указывается в секундах, текущее - 5 минут

while True :
    # основные действия
    if time.time() > start_time + CLOSE_AFTER: break
```

Comment: А в основных действия будет что-то блокирующее текущий поток вроде sleep, отправки запроса, дикий цикл с обработкой :) т.е. выходит что сама программа не может контролировать свое время выполнения будучи в одном потоке/процессе. По хорошему, тут нужно работу сценария вынести в отдельный поток и убивать главный поток через указанное время. Поток при этом должен быть демоном -- чтобы его вручную не нужно было убивать. В принципе, то что я писал в ответе nick_gabpe описано :)